# PDF Expiry Date

Tags: javascript, pdf

I've written a confidential proposal for a client using Adobe InDesign.

To prevent the client sharing this document with anyone else (e.g. a competitor), I'd like to set an expiry date on the exported PDF.

I've read that this is possible with JavaScript, but the security using this method is relatively low. I need a solution which verifies the date and time via a server rather than a desktop or mobile device.

Is this possible?

Comment: What happens when the client takes a photo of the PDF with his phone and then sends the image to a competitor? To be honest I think you'd be wasting your time with a self-destructing document. Just get the client's agreement in writing and then sue the hell out of them if they break the contract. Note: I am not your lawyer.

Comment: Ha ha, good point! You'd be surprised how many of my clients don't know how to print screen... Nevertheless, I'd be interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: What shall happen for clients using PDF viewers without JavaScript support?

Comment: Another good point. I've found Adobe [LiveCycle] (http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/livecycle.html) which appears to be the tool that is used for rights management.

Comment: There are a few other Digital Rights Management tools out there, such as FileOpen by FileOpen. Some vendors also offer the tool as a service, for places where only a small number of documents has to be protected

Comment: FileOpen looks like an excellent solution, thank you.